# Fallout PnP RPG -- is it good, well balanced, long-term interesting?

Tags: fallout-pnp-rpg

Has anyone played the [Fallout PnP RPG](http://nma-fallout.com/forum/dload.php?action=file&file_id=775)? (also available [here](http://fallout-rpg.narod.ru/PnP.html).) I think the rulebook looks very exciting, but what experiences have you made? Are the rules sane? Are there pitfalls or shortcomings which are only apparent once you started playing? Also, on a sidenote, how do you think about playing dogs or robots? Not that I would try it when playing for the first time, though, I'm just curious … and how many hours/evenings/… have you usually spent on one adventure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the original Fallout PnP rules are good and solid. Also very good for new players who just played the CRPGs. It's a percentile system so its bonus/penalty modifiers is easy to apply.
Other than that it is really easy to die, easy to kill system (for humans, at least). And this is a real plus for a Fallout game, if you ask me.
Though the game actually have species other than human (deathclaw, super mutant, dog or robot to name a few), I never used those. Because they hinder the fallout-ish feeling of the game. 
Aaand, also the sound of multiple dice (a lot) hitting the table while making a full automatic shot is awesome.

Comment: Sweet. Are you GM? Have you played with players of other species?

Comment: Sorry for very late reply. I have GM'd Fallout PnP a bunch of times. I also started to translate the rules to my language (but never compleated  =)).
As I said in my original answer, I never used the non-human species in my games. Not as a GM nor player.

Answer (score 0):

For my money it's always better to 'port' house rules to an established system, eg d20 Modern or GURPS. This way you get the 'native flavor' of the setting with the larger universe of expansions and source material.

Comment: Interesting, but that amounts to some serious work! I think I'd rather play it in its original form. (There is an errata sheet already for it, it can't be that bad -- people seem to have played it and commented!)

Comment: There are quite a few people who strongly dislike porting everything over to one's favorite system. It often renders the settings into bland pastiches, rather than doing the setting justice. Some GM's can pull it off, many can't. Plus it's a sh*load of work which is usually in vain.