# Fallout 3 Role Playing Game

Tags: game-recommendation

I am new into role playing and I feel that it is something that I want to do more often but the setting of D&D seems like something I wouldn't be so much into. I would rather play it on a setting that reminds of you the video game fallout 3. Are there any existing Fallout 3 games? or anything similar? are they easy to understand and play? would it be easier to create my own, from scratch or using the basic settings of another RPG? at the end of the day the two main elements are that the setting is similar to that of fallout 3 and that its easy.

Comment: Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5217/what-game-system-is-best-for-playing-fallout-on-the-tabletop
Oh, and welcome to RPG.SE!

Comment: Also [Related] [Fallout PnP RPG -- is it good, well balanced, long-term interesting?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5287)

Comment: There are different kinds of easy. Did you want a game wherein the gamemaster concocts things on the fly? Did you want a game without a lot of math? Did you want a game without a lot of bookkeeping? When you imagine sitting down and playing the game, what does it look like that makes it easy?